# Limit of ratio goes to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

I  am trying to show, if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=0$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=0.$$

I figured there exists an $\epsilon_N$ such that the following holds
$$|a_{N+1}|< \epsilon_N |a_N|$$

and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\epsilon_{N}=0.$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}\ne  \infty$, then $\lim_{N\to \infty}\epsilon_{N}*|a_{N}|=0.$

One can conclude $\lim_{N\to \infty}|a_{N+1}|=0$. Is this correct? Is there another way to show this?

Comment: Btw, you can use `\lim` for limits.

Comment: Contrapositive statement is easier to prove in my opinion: if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\neq0$

Comment: In order to prove that $\epsilon_N\to0$ implies $\epsilon_N\lvert a_N\rvert\to 0$, you should prove that $\lvert a_N\rvert$ does not diverge.

Comment: @Gae.S. If I can show it does not diverge then is the rest correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @79037662 The contrapositive should also consider the case when the limit does not exist.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the ratio and divergence tests for series, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ implies $\sum a_n < \infty$, which in turn implies $a_n \to 0$ by the divergence test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<\frac12$. Then

- $|a_{N+1}|\leqslant\frac12|a_N|$;
- $|a_{N+2}|\leqslant\frac1{2^2}|a_N|$;
- $\vdots$
- $|a_{N+k}|\leqslant\frac1{2^k}|a_N|$

and therefore $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{N+k}=0$, from which it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: It's a duplicate (I found this while looking for a dup target for https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4372919/42969).

Answer (score 0):

This is more like killing a mosquito with a sledge hammer but I will give it a try: As $\vert\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\vert=0$, then $\sum \vert a_n\vert<\infty$, so it should also be: $\lim \vert a_n\vert =\lim a_n = 0$.